# как изменить только X в rect transform?

Tags: c#, unity3d

я пытаюсь изменить только X позицию у объекта который находится в canvas делаю я эта при помощи:

```
obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x + 100, 0, 0);
```

но при этом у меня меняется Y вместе с X и то не в правильные координаты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localPosition` имеет тип `Vector3` которому нужно на вход дать именно его и никак иначе. Поэтому либо делать так:

```
obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x + 100, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);
```

либо

```
Vector3 localPos = transform.localPosition;
localPos.x = desiredXData;
transform.localPosition = localPos;
```